# Convert values to keys mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Following is the result of an aggregation query:

```
[
    {
         "_id": "5a9433fee5878a000f7cba09",
         "trendingStats": {
            "trendingArr": [],
            "trendingScore": 0
         }
    },
   {
       "_id": "5a942f79e5878a000f7cba06",
       "trendingStats": {
          "trendingArr": [],
          "trendingScore": 0
       }
   }
]
```

This is the query:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {$project:{
         'trendingStats':{
           '$ifNull':['$trendingStats',{'trendingArr':[],'trendingScore':0}
         }
    }
]);
```

I want the result to be one document with the following format:

```
{'5a9433fee5878a000f7cba09':{'trendingArr':[],trendingStats:0},
 '5a942f79e5878a000f7cba06':{'trendingArr':[],trendingStats:0},
}
```

Is there a way I can transform the result into the one document like that ?

Comment: I would strongly advise you **don't** just as the linked duplicate concludes with. You can get away with it if your entire result is under 16MB, but it's basically faster and cleaner to code to simply "compact the document" once the cursor result is sent to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below stages after the `$project`

```
{ "$group": {
  "_id": null,
  "data": {
    "$push": {
      "k": { "$toString": "$_id" },
      "v": "$trendingStats"
    }
  }
}},
{ "$replaceRoot": {
  "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
}}
```

[**`Output`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DOvK-NdWbUY)

```
[
  {
    "5a942f79e5878a000f7cba06": {
      "trendingArr": [],
      "trendingScore": 0
    },
    "5a9433fee5878a000f7cba09": {
      "trendingArr": [],
      "trendingScore": 0
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: `"k": { "$toString": "$_id" }` - Without that you will throw an exception due to `ObjectId` not being a "string".

Comment: @NeilLunn Yupss you are right as always. Updated the answer.

Comment: getting an exception `Unrecognized expression '$toString'`

Comment: @user3302146 You must have latest mongodb version i.e. 4.0. Are you on?

Comment: its version 3.6

Comment: @user3302146 You have to upgrade to latest version or you can follow the duplicate answer.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I think i'll go with the suggestion of handling this on the client. Thank you for your help.